# Mysql error when adding line that copies id to another row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code that does this query and works as expected:

```
INSERT INTO items (name) VALUES (\'TEC TEST !"#!12\')
```

But when I add this line to the end of it, it fails:

```
; SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM ".$table_name."; UPDATE ".$table_name." SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id;
```

I searched all over google and stackoverflow, but can't find any cases that matches my problem :(

My php calling code is:

```
$table_name = $this->_request['table']; 
$data = $this->_request['data'];

$sql0 = "INSERT INTO ".$table_name." (";
$sql1 = " VALUES (";
foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $sql0 .= $key.",";
    if(is_array($value)) { 
        if($value[1] == 'date')             
            $sql1 .=  $this->db_escape($value[0]).",";
        if($value[1] == 'float')
            $sql1 .= $value.",";
    }else 
        $sql1 .= $this->db_escape($value).",";
}
$sql0 = substr($sql0, 0, -1).")";
$sql1 = substr($sql1, 0, -1).")";
$sql2 = "SELECT @last_id := MAX(id) FROM items; UPDATE items SET sortingId = id WHERE id = @last_id;";

$string = stripslashes($sql0.$sql1.$sql2);

$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql0.$sql1.$sql2);
if(mysqli_insert_id($this->db) > 0){                
    $this->response($this->json(array( 'inserted_id' => mysqli_insert_id($this->db))), 200);
}

$error = array('status' => "Failed", "msg" => "Failed To Insert ".$string);
$this->response($this->json($error), 400);
```

**UPDATE:**

Calling like this completes without error, but sortingId is 0 on the newly created row. It should be the Int of id which is generated from auto_increment

```
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql0.$sql1);
$sql = mysqli_query($this->db, $sql2);

if(mysqli_insert_id($this->db) > 0){                
    $this->response($this->json(array( 'inserted_id' => mysqli_insert_id($this->db))), 200);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do multi query with  mysqli_query, it's good idea to always seperate the queries.

If you really can't do something else, there is this function in PHP :

```
mysqli_multiquery(...)
```

Comment: Ohh, thanks! See my update. No errors anymore, but still dosen't do the correct job

Comment: you won't get the id because it will stop on the first ; and sql2 start with this one !

Comment: Arh! Thanks Daniel